# Can I code parameters directly into this macro or do I have to add them in each cell?

Tags: microsoft-excel, vba

I'm using this macro to identify cells that contain non-alphanumeric characters:

```
Function RegExCheck(objCell As Range, strPattern As String)

    Dim RegEx As Object
    Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    RegEx.Global = True
    RegEx.Pattern = strPattern

    If RegEx.Replace(objCell.Value, "") = objCell.Value Then
        RegExCheck = 0
    Else
        RegExCheck = 1
    End If

End Function
```

In this example, I can specify the characters for which I'm looking in the cell itself:

```
=RegExCheck(A1,"[^A-Za-z0-9_-]")
```

Since the characters for which I'm searching in each cell are the same, is there a way I can add the `"[^A-Za-z0-9_-]"` into the macro module and simply use `=RegExCheck(A1)` to output the results?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Of course, simply set `strPattern` inside the function:

```
Function RegExCheck(objCell As Range)
Dim strPattern As String
strPattern = "[^A-Za-z0-9_-]"
... [rest of code] ...
End Function
```

Or you can skip using another variable altogether and do:

```
Function RegExCheck(objCell as Range)
...
RegEx.Pattern = "[^A-Za-z0-9_-]"
...
End Function
```

But I recommend keeping the variable as in my first example.  That makes it easier to reuse that pattern within the function, and is a logical place to check...rather than having to read through lines of code looking for your pattern. (That's more applicable for longer functions/subs, but IMO is a best practice).

Edit: You didn't really ask, but FYI you could also store the pattern in a cell (say `B1`) and reference that cell to get the pattern.  That would let you relatively quickly change the pattern if you need:

```
Function RegExCheck(objCell as Range, patternCell as Range)
...
RegEx.Pattern = patternCell.Value
....
End Function
```

But when you call this, make sure to anchor the `patternCell` reference, i.e. `=REGEXCHECK(A1,$B$1)`

Edit: To be explicit, this should work:

```
Function RegExCheck(objCell As Range)
    Dim strPattern As String
    strPattern = "[^A-Za-z0-9_-]"
    Dim RegEx As Object
    Set RegEx = CreateObject("VBScript.RegExp")
    RegEx.Global = True
    RegEx.Pattern = strPattern

    If RegEx.Replace(objCell.Value, "") = objCell.Value Then
        RegExCheck = 0
    Else
        RegExCheck = 1
    End If

End Function
```

Comment: I tried using your top suggestion--[beginning the code with that and then picking up with If RegEx... from my original code.](https://pastebin.com/DPzdV2qD) But this produces a VALUE error. What am I doing wrong?

Comment: @user2258740 you never use `strPattern` in that code.

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. The code I posted to Pastebin includes `"strPattern = "[^A-Za-z0-9_-]"`

Comment: @user2258740 that simply assigns a string to the variable. You need to use the pattern. See in your original code how you do `RegEx.Pattern = strPattern`?

Comment: @user2258740 - See my edit. Does that do it?

Comment: @user2258740 Yay! (If it works, you can flag it as The Answer by clicking the check mark left of the post. This will also remove the question from the Unanswered queue.)